# Search using view and facet as block

Tags: views, 8, search

In my project I need facet search as block view that need to be included in content region. So I created View as block and added facet block in header of the view. Also need infinite scroll, so enabled ajax in view. So issue is that facet search ajax and View ajax causing conflict so that the query parameters are duplicating in URL.

http://localhost.com/sample-page?q=/sample-page?q=/sample-page?filter[0]=category_filter:171&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax&filter[0]=category_filter:171&filter[1]=category_filter:173&filter[2]=category_filter:174

Is there any workaround to fix this? Any patch is available for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I applied this patch 
https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-07-31/facets-3070461-3-Facet-links-break-in-modal_0.patch and issue resolved. Hope this will be helpful for others.